# Excel2Latex Table producing error

Tags: tables, excel2latex

I am using Excel2Latex to create tables but I got the following errors: ! Undefined control sequence.

I have installed the multirow and multicol package, I really apppreciate your help.

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Artículo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Autor}} & \textbf{Año} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1     & \cite{Croxton2003} & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    2     & Ballou & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    3     & Kalkowski & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code works perfectly fine, provided that you use the `bigstrut` package (for the homonymous command)  and `amssymb`(for the `\checkmark` command). In addition to table 1 that is basically the table from the question, I have added two alternatives. In table 2 I have used the `makecell` package  in order to avoid repeated `\bigstrut` commands as well as `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf...}`. In table 3 I have removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal lines by the lines from the `booktabs` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%% Used for all tables %%
\usepackage{amssymb}

%% only for table 1 %%
\usepackage{bigstrut}

%% only for table 2 and 3 %%
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{3pt}

%% only for table 3 %%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Artículo}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Autor}} & \textbf{Año} \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    1     & \cite{Croxton2003} & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    2     & Ballou & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    3     & Kalkowski & \checkmark \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\begin{table}[htbp]
\makegapedcells
  \centering
  \caption{with the help of the makecell package}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|l|c|}
    \hline
    \thead{Artículo} & \thead{Autor} & \thead{Año} \\
    \hline
    1     & \cite{Croxton2003} & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    2     & Ballou & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    3     & Kalkowski & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%


\begin{table}[htbp]
  \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
  \centering
  \caption{with the help of the booktabs package}
    \begin{tabular}{llc}
    \toprule
    \thead{Artículo} & \thead{Autor} & \thead{Año} \\
    \midrule
    1     & \cite{Croxton2003} & \checkmark \\
    2     & Ballou & \checkmark \\
    3     & Kalkowski & \checkmark \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! when i use the package that you mentione it worked perfectly.

Comment: @MarcoHeredia: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Sorry for bother leandriis but I want to create a table needed and once again I have the same issue:

Comment: @MarcoHeredia: Please post a follow up question with a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the error you describe.